# PreparedStatement setString(...) for all, even if corrsponding data type is an integer

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have come across the following codes i feel it is doing the wrong thing:

(Note that this is JDK 1.4.2, therefore the list is not typed)

```
StringBuffer queryBuffer = new StringBuffer();
ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();

... 
queryBuffer.append("and sb.POSTCODE = ? ");
temp.add(postcode);
...

conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();       
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuffer.toString());
```

This is what i am concerned about:

```
for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++) {
    log.debug("setString("+ (i+1) + "," + (String)temp.get(i) + ")");
    pstmt.setString(i+1, (String)temp.get(i));
}
```

But i have noted that some of the corresponding data types (field) in the database are integer, and dates, would this be alright?

Comment: I don't think it is good. Seems this is relying on implicit conversion, and that often leads to grief down the road.

Comment: I'm guessing `temp` is a `List` - is it generically typed? Please show its declaration.

Comment: @Paul Bellora temp is an ArrayList. And its not typed because this is Java 1.4

Comment: ArrayList<?????> i.e. ArrayList of WHAT?

Comment: @Jim Garrison it is not typed, JDK 1.4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using the PreparedStatement [setObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method instead of **setString()**.

The PreparedStatement **setObject()** will attempt to convert any of the **java.lang** types for you if the type is unknown at compile time.

so with an updated for loop (assuming you have java 5.0) and generic null handling:

```
int i = 0;
for(Object value : temp) {
    if (value == null) {
        // set null parameter if value type is null and type is unknown
        pstmt.setNull(++i, Integer.MIN_VALUE); 
    } else {
        pstmt.setObject(++i, value);
    }
}
```

Note that [setNull()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) can accept a [type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) as the 2nd parameter if it is known.

Comment: Thanks pd40, i would make a small note that setObject would be useful in situations when the type is unknown during compile time.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `setObject()` in this case. Beware, you shouldn't pass untyped `null` to `setObject()`. +1

Comment: Good point about the null case. I'll add that. Also the comment about compile time.

Comment: Does using setObject() increase the possibility of SQL injection at all?

Answer (score 0):

This didn't help me. 
Below is the query built after appending the bind variables.
select ACC_NO from ACC_TABLE where ACC_NAME='java.lang.String';

It is trying to convert to java.lang.String type and which results in the following exception
java.sql.SQLException: Could not execute sql command - Original message: null

Where as my ACC_NAME is 'user01'.
So actually the query should be some thing like this,
select ACC_NO from ACC_TABLE where ACC_NAME='user01';

So if my understanding is not wrong, preparedStatement.setObject(index, object) is converting the data to its respective data type and setting it.

preparedStatement.setObject(index, object) in MySQL is working perfectly alright with no issues.
Only problem is while using Oracle. 
Oracle DB version i am working with is

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production