# In Java DB2 JDBC: How can one use null parameters in a WHERE clause for a SELECT statement where the value can be either null or not null?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement

For example I have the following select query for a PreparedStatement:

"SELECT FOO FROM BAR WHERE FOOBAR=?"

The parameter for FOOBAR can have a value and it could also be null.

Would the following code work?

```
if(<condition>) preparedStatement.setString(1, "<string value>");
else preparedStatement.setString(1, null);
```

If not, how should this be handled?

Comment: have you tried the code with null value?

Comment: Not yet, since the main query that drives my program takes a couple of hours to execute. I'm working with hundreds of thousands of rows.

I figured asking might be faster than setting up a dummy program just to test this specific inqury.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610950/preparedstatement-setstring-for-all-even-if-corrsponding-data-type-is-an-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't work, null has no equivalence. If you're using a PreparedStatement, try this:

```
if(<condition>) preparedStatement.setObject(1, "<string value>");
else preparedStatement.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
```

It will send the null as an IN parameter.

Comment: thanks. this seems like a solution that could work. will try.

Comment: If that doesn't work, make sure java.sql.Types is imported or make it java.sql.Types.VARCHAR.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse imported java.sql.Types on its own. It seems to be working. program has been running for 40 minutes without any problems. It should be done in an hour or so. Will know then for sure if it has worked when I verify the data. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

As per SQL standard, if a column has a NULL value, the search condition to check if it has NULL value is "column IS NULL". If column does not have null value you can have condition such as "column = 'blabla'. To make parameter markers work in both cases, change the statement as following:

```
SELECT FOO FROM BAR WHERE COALESCE(FOOBAR, 'a') = ? "
```

and have the following code:

```
if(<condition>) preparedStatement.setString(1, "<string value>");
else preparedStatement.setString(1, "a");
```

Whatever @Mark suggested did not work for me on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a null valued parameter and null values in a column.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(requiredValue == null){
 sql = "SELECT * FROM Table Where COLUMN is NULL"
}
```

You don't have to set the value in this case.

Comment: do I have to prepare the statement again when I encounter a null value (because I initially set it up to take in a parameter)? e.g.


`if(requiredValue is null){ 
 sql = "SELECT * FROM Table Where COLUMN is NULL"
 preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
}`

Comment: yes. its based on your design. But I would do like this

String sql = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
if(conditon){
  sql = NULL SQL thing
  ps = new PreparedStatement(sql);
}else{
  sql = NOT NULL SQL thing
    ps = new PreparedStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(........)
}

Comment: hmmmm. I'm thinking my program might take a performance hit from preparing the statement repeatedly with each iteration of the loop.

in which case, I think it might be better to setup two statements: one for a null value and another for a non-null value... but it seems like a crude approach.

Comment: As I said it depends on your design. I can't see any performance issue here. I can't see your complete code calling logic. so no comments :)

Comment: @heisenbergman DB2 caches prepared statements, so there would be very little overhead in having 2 different prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the performance gain from using a single prepared statement lost if you'd have to prepare it over and over again, thus requiring the system to compile it over and over again as well?