# security in java prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I read about SQL injection and a way to prevent them with `preparedStatement`,.
so I create a generic prototype SQL class that will get query and parameters. 
Then it merge the query and the parameters together and ran it.

```
public List select(String query, String [] prepString) throws Exception {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
            //statement = connect.createStatement();
            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);

            for(int i = 0; i < prepString.length ; i++){
                preparedStatement.setString(i+1, prepString[i]);    
            }

            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            return resultSetToArrayList(resultSet);
```

Can I use `setString` for everything?
Because I also saw `preparedStatement.setInt` and `preparedStatement.setBoolean` functions, and it made me confuse because I know that the SQL query send as a String to the server.

does it wont work with other types? or it just less secure?

Edit: I saw some folks who offer to use `setObject()` in [PreparedStatement setString(...) for all, even if corrsponding data type is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610950/preparedstatement-setstring-for-all-even-if-corrsponding-data-type-is-an-i)

But if we send SQL query as a string, why do we need to specify the type anyway? Does it add special type parameter inside the query?

Comment: Thanks for the link. They do offer to use setObject, but don't explain why.

Comment: As a side node: whether your approach is secure depends on where `query` comes from. If an attacker could insert code there (which is one thing that prepared statements are meant to prevent by escaping parameter values) then using a prepared statement is not of much use.

Comment: I am making the query. The attacker can only insert the values.

Comment: As for the link: `setObject()` probably checks the type of the object that is being passed and then calls the correct setter, i.e. if you pass in a String it calls `setString()` (or an equivalent) and if you pass an Integer it calls `setInt()`.

Comment: Yes but why do we need it? you send sql query in string no? do you add special int parameter in the query?

Comment: For _`setString`_ "The driver converts this to an SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR", so it will be escaped as such. Sure, most of the time the DB will accept quoted integers and such, but there is no guarantee. For _`setObject`_ "The given argument will be converted to the corresponding SQL type before being sent to the database" , and so it will be escaped as the corresponding SQL type should be.

Comment: So you say there is an escape per parameter type? 
Interesting, I need to search more about that. You should definitely put it as an answer.